# IP Address to Use for Google API Key restriction on AWS EC2

Tags: google-maps, amazon-ec2, google-geocoding-api

I am using an AWS EC2 instance. using an Elastic IP associated to it.

I use that Elastic IP for Google API Key restriction, but it seems the IP is still not allowed as the referrer.

What IP excactly need to be used for it?

When the restriction is set to none, the api is working fine.

Regards

Comment: The ip/domain required should be in the error message in the javascript console..

Comment: If you use Maps JavaScript API the restriction should be of type HTTP referrer, not an IP restrictions. The domain to authorize appears in error message.

Comment: This is a piece of documentation about API key restrictions: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#using-google-maps-apis

Comment: It will output the IP in the error message, but elastic IP's change. If your server's IP address ever changes, it will stop working.

Comment: This probably doesn't help much, but here's the (LONG) list of EC2 IP addresses you'd have to whitelist. 
https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json